# How do I perform subtraction of two different sized matrices efficiently in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I am trying to calculate the differences between two large matrices. One of the matrices has more years of data than the other, so it has more rows and columns. Essentially, I would like to ignore the extra data and only consider the comparable data, with the extra data added on the end.

Is there a way to do this without using for loops that will work on large matrices or data frames?

This is the first time I have asked a question on this forum, so please correct my question as necessary or let me know how to amend it. Thank you

I have a minimal working example below, but would like a more elegant and scalable solution that does not use nested for loops.

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
B <- c(1,2,3,4)

AA <- matrix(A, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
BB <- matrix(B, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

differences <- AA

for (i in 1:nrow(BB)){
   for (j in 1:ncol(BB)){
     differences[i,j] <- differences[i,j] - BB[i,j]
   }
}

differences
```

This returns

```
0  1  7
0  1  8
3  6  9
```

which is correct. However, I can't help but feel there must be a better (more efficient) way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An adjustment of [@Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75873515/10068985):

```r
do.call(\(x, y) `[<-`(AA, x, y, AA[x, y] - BB), list(seq_len(nrow(BB)), seq_len(ncol(BB))))
```

which only needs to evaluate `seq_len(nrow(BB))` and `seq_len(ncol(BB))` once.

Another idea (but slower):

```r
AA - `[<-`(array(0, dim(AA)), seq_len(nrow(BB)), seq_len(ncol(BB)), BB)
```

Output:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    1    7
# [2,]    0    1    8
# [3,]    3    6    9
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy way with your example, but you may need to adjust it in other cases (e.g. when BB is the larger matrix):

```
CC <- AA
CC[seq(nrow(BB)), seq(ncol(BB))] <- AA[seq(nrow(BB)), seq(ncol(BB))] - BB
CC
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    1    7
# [2,]    0    1    8
# [3,]    3    6    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Same solution as given in the answers, but works no matter the dimmensions of AA and BB

```
differences <- function(x, y) {
  rN <- min(nrow(x), nrow(y))
  cN <- min(ncol(x), ncol(y))
  x[seq_len(rN), seq_len(cN)] <- x[seq_len(rN), seq_len(cN)] - y[seq_len(rN), seq_len(cN)]
  x
}

differences(AA, BB)
```